# When applying non-increasing functions to $a > b$, any general method to tell when to change the sign?

Tags: inequality

If we have

$$
a > b
$$

then we can conclude:

$$
f(a) > f(b)
$$

only if $f$ is an increasing function. If instead $f$ is a decreasing function, then we flip the sign and conclude:

$$
f(a) < f(b)
$$

What if $f$ is neither increasing or decreasing? Is it always possible to know whether the sign should be flipped?

For example, consider $f(x) = x^2$. This function is increasing on the positive numbers and decreasing on the negative numbers, so when considering if we can apply it to both sides of $a > b$ we have three cases:

- Both $a$ and $b$ are positive. Then $a^2 > b^2$.
- Both $a$ and $b$ are negative. Then $a^2 < b^2$.
- $a$ and $b$ have different signs. Then we don't know whether to flip; for example, if $a = 2$, $b = -3$ then we should flip (since $9 > 4$) but if $a = 10$, $b = -1$ then we should not.

But in the third case we can decide to flip or not to flip by using a different function -- we compare the absolute values. If $|b| > |a|$, then we flip; else, we do not.

**I'm looking for a general theory** (if there is one) which addresses the problem of deciding whether we need to flip the sign when applying any function $f$ to both sides of $a > b$. I'm curious about why absolute value turned out to be the auxiliary function in the case of $f(x) = x^2$, and what this process would look like for other functions.

Comment: you mean flip the inequality, sign +s $+$ or $-$. As for it, derivatives is the answer.

Comment: In general the only way is to calculate $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ and compare them.

Answer (score 1):

If you have $a<b$ and $f$ is neither (strictly) increasing nor decreasing then you know nothing about whether $f(a)<f(b), f(a)>f(b)$ or maybe $f(a)=f(b)$.

If $f$ is increasing on an interval $I$, then you can conclude: $f(a)<f(b)$, if $a,b\in I$. Similarly if it is decreasing.

Deciding whether a function is increasing / decreasing on an interval may be easy or very hard (for example, take the function $f(x) = x + 1$, if the Riemann Hypothesis holds and $f(x) = x - 1$ if it does not, for all $x$. You can't say, whether $f$ is increasing or decreasing without deciding the Riemann Hypothesis first). There is not really a theory for proving such statements.
The only "general theory" here is that of logic and set theory.